# Prove that one can choose $(X, d)$ and $A$ such that $A = Is A$ but yet $A$ is not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I wonder if this following example, $A = \{\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ under the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ fits - does it?

Comment: What do you mean by $IsA$?

Comment: "$IsA$" means what, the set of isolated points of $A$?

Comment: Yeah, this example works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all points of $A$ are isolated, but $0 \in \overline{A}\setminus A$.